# Excel using INDEX and multiple MATCH

Tags: excel

I am having trouble using INDEX and MATCH functions in excel. Say I have the following data:

```
A        B       C      D
Year   Month   Site   Count
2004     3      X1      54
2006     6      X3      10
2005     10     X5      15
```

And I want to arrange it like this

```
E        F      G       H      I      J       K
Year   Month    X1      X2     X3     X4      X5
2004     1
2004     2
2004     3      54            
2004     4
2004     5
2004     6
```

...

```
2005     10                     10
```

...

```
2006     6                                   15
```

I have the following formula (I want to match the Site, Year and Month):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(G$1,$C$2:$C$4,0),MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH($F2,$B$2:$B$4,0)),"")
```

and it seems to work fine for the first column (G) but when I autofill the rest of the columns (H:K) it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: One problem is the Year Month combinations in cols A:B don't match the ones in E:F.

Comment: @cpilko oops sorry, that was a typo - they do now (and do in my data set)

Comment: It seems that the Count isn't going in the correct year/month row. Not sure why...

Comment: Is each row unique, or could there be multiple rows returned from March 2004?

Comment: @cpilko There are multiple entries for March 2004 but only one for Site X1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a different approach than using all these nested matches, and create a searchable column with unique values and `MATCH` that column to get a row to feed into the `INDEX`.

Insert 2 rows between Cols D and E, putting the 2nd appearance of 'Year' in Column G. (Because I like some whitespace)

Paste this formula in E2 and copy it to E3:E4

```
=CONCATENATE(C2,"-",A2,"-",B2)
```

If it bothers you, hide Column E.

Then paste this formula in I2 and copy it to I2:M4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(CONCATENATE(I$1,"-",$G2,"-",$H2),$E$2:$E$4,0),0),"")
```